# How to order columns in DataGrid by date/time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that displays notes for a customer form. So if something in the form gets changed a note is created saying what changes where made. Right now the newest notes gets put to the bottom of the list. But how do I switch that around so the newest notes are at the top?

```
<div id="tabNotesComments" runat="server">
    <div>
        Notes/Comments for the customer
        <asp:DataGrid CssClass="tblResults" runat="server" ID="dgNotes" OnItemDataBound="dgNotes_ItemDataBound" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Entered By"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DateString" HeaderText="Date"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TimeString" HeaderText="Time"></asp:BoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see in the image what I mean. See how the most recent note is at the bottom. I want to display this list in reverse so the newest notes are displayed first.

[image]

Code for binding DataGrid:

```
dgNotes.DataSource = c.NotesList;
dgNotes.DataBind();
```

**Answer**
Thanks for Dimitris Batsougiannis's answer I used reverse:

```
dgNotes.DataSource = c.NotesList;
c.NotesList.Reverse();
dgNotes.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the Reverse [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c6526tb(v=vs.110).aspx) ?